# Why are MTU sizes checked by "netsh interface ip show subinterfaces" and "ping google.com -l 1472 -f" different?

Tags: android-fragments, mtu

I am checking the MTU size of a USB tethering connection, but I got different results with different commands...

By using "netsh interface ip show subinterfaces" I get the following results (Local Area Connection 8 is the tethering connection):

C:\Users\Chris>netsh interface ip show subinterfaces

MTU  MediaSenseState   Bytes In  Bytes Out  Interface

---

4294967295                1          0    1350760  Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
  1500                2  3756376356  10363121083  Wireless Network Connection
  1500                5          0          0  Local Area Connection
  1500                1     178477     238360  Local Area Connection 8

But by using "ping google.com -l 1472 -f" I got the following results:

C:\Users\Chris>ping google.com -l 1472 -f

Pinging google.com [216.58.220.142] with 1472 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.42.129: Packet needs to be fragmented but DF set.
Packet needs to be fragmented but DF set.
Packet needs to be fragmented but DF set.
Packet needs to be fragmented but DF set.

The tethering connection is the only working connection when I check. If the MTU size is 1500 the ping method should work... I am a little bit confused here. Could anyone tell me what's the difference between the 2 method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`netsh` shows the MTU of the interface itself. But your `ping` command sends packets through your interface into the wider world of the Internet. Somewhere along the path between your interface and google.com there is a router with a smaller MTU than 1472 bytes. This is called Path MTU.